# How to update cookies across directories in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

Is there any way to update cookies across folders in PHP?
For example, consider the following directory structure:

- A is the parent directory and has two parallel children folders B and
  C.
- In A, there is a page called a.php.
- In A/B, there is a page called b.php.
- In A/C, there is a page called c.php.

Now, I do the following 3 things:

- setcookie("num" 1) in a.php
- setcookie("num" ,10) to update the cookie in b.php
- setcookie("num" , "", time()-3600) to clear the cookie in c.php

But, in my test run, because b.php and c.php are not in the same directory level as a.php, I can't update the cookie in b.php and c.php. The only thing I can do in b.php and c.php is read the cookie.
I only can update cookie in pages which are also in A.

However, in the real cases it is common to store different pages in the different folders.

Do we must update cookies in the pages which has the same directory level as that in which the cookie is originally set?

My php version : 5.2.6

If there is any further information I can provide in order to better describe the problem, please let me know!
Thank you.

Comment: Very good formatting for a first question. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Truth The original question has been heavily edited by other users on SO. You can see who last edited the question besides the OP's name.

Comment: @Abbas, lol, I posted that comment before the edits. It wasn't THAT heavily edited, in fact, I am the one who approved the edit.

Comment: @Truth Oh, well, in that case +1 for your comment. But hats off to all the editors, the before- and after-edit look of some questions can  be submitting to an editing competition. Disclosure: this is self-admiration to an extent, I have been involved in a lot of editing lately ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) accepts a `path` argument which will set the path at which the cookie applies. Simply add it to the `setcookie` call, something like `setcookie('num', 1, 3600, '/');`

A path of `/` will mean it's available for the entire domain.